# Is it possible in apache-arrow to create parts of vectors in separate threads with the Java API?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-arrow

In apache arrow is it possible to create vectors in parallel (different threads)? I assumed that because of the setPosition(...) call in writers, the order of creation of entries in the vector is not relevant. But when I tried to do it in parallel threads, I ran into errors. When I do it sequentially it works fine. I am using the ComplexWriterImpl with a sub-writer for each field.

Actual error is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ref count should be >= 1 for accessing the ArrowBuf

I am interested to know, if the creation of vectors via writers in arrow (in Java) is designed to be possible out of order and with parallel threads.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify how calls are being parallelized.  If you have threads writing to different locations using the same writer that will lead to trouble.  [setPosition](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/vector/src/main/codegen/templates/ComplexWriters.java#L90) isn't thread-safe and `write` calls [`setSafe()`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/vector/src/main/codegen/templates/ComplexWriters.java#L103) which can potentially resize the buffer.

I can't think of a technical reason off the top of my head why single threaded out-of-order updates wouldn't work.  However, I'm not sure if that is setPosition was originally designed for (I think the more typical use case is skipping the write for null values).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I managed to write columns in parallel by using actors, but in order. This way I could reduce the creation time by 50%. Now reading from disk and arrow creation is on par in terms of speed and this was my goal.